# Remap Keyboard Keys based on what keyboard being used

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, xmodmap

I have a `Dell XPS13` and I'm using a `Keychron K2` keyboard. The keyboard layouts are different.

Is there a way of mapping different keys on the different keyboards? Either at the same time or some sort of easily accessed switch.

I usually have the `Ctrl` and `Alt` swapped, but they are different keys on the keyboards and the `Fn` key is located on the right side with the `Keychron k2`.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution ended up being even easier than going through xmodmap.

In Keyboard > Layouts > Options..., there's a keyboard Layout Option for "Ctrl position". I just checked "Right Ctrl as Right Alt" and "Swap Left Alt with Left Ctrl".

Both keyboards work as intended now.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a possibility to automatically switch keyboard layouts depending on the keyboard that is in use. However, you can conveniently install more than a single keyboard layout in your system, and then switch between the keyboard layouts using a hotkey, which by default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

In "Settings" - "Region and Languages", you can add another keyboard layout by clicking the <kbd>+</kbd> button under "Input Sources". You can change the hotkeys to switch forwards and backwards between different keyboard layouts (useful if you have more than two different layouts active) in "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts" under the "Typing" section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that out and get back. Sounds like a solution to me.